# Maven FindBugs report showing difference between two builds

Tags: maven, findbugs

Do any of you know of a plugin of some kind which can evaluate the difference between two html reports? I am using maven findbugs plugin to generate xml and translate html reports with every maven build.

However, I wish to take this a step further by showing the bugs or warnings generated in that build only. i.e. the difference between the previous report and this one.

For example if I have 25 warnings in the first build and I have resolved 2 of them and generated two other warnings, I want a report that shows that these 2 has been resolved and these 2 are new.

Do you know of any way?

Comment: Not exactly what you are asking for but I am using the Static Code Analysis plugin for Jenkins (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Static+Code+Analysis+Plug-ins#StaticCodeAnalysisPlug-ins-trend) which is quite helpful and nearly what you are looking for. (As an alternative you could always make a diff)

Comment: Yeah I know about that, thanks, but we are using SonarQube to show these differences remotely. What I'm after is a difference between local builds (before remote commit). Any suggestions about how the diff can be carried out?

Comment: I would probably copy the report after generating it via Maven to an extra folder (so that you don't overwrite the old report) and use e.g. WinMerge (http://winmerge.org/) to let me show the differences.